# DataModel usage with FileItemSimilarity in Mahout

Tags: java, mahout

I'm building a recommender where the actual similarity computation is done with the ItemSimilarityJob and which is then loaded into a non distributed recommender through FileItemSimilarity.

All this works so far(2), but there's one thing I'm a bit puzzled about.

When instantiating the recommender (GenericItemBasedRecommender), I've to pass along a data model - which would be FileDataModel in my case, but due to the fact that the similarity computation already took place, I don't really know what data I should pass into the model?

Clearly the model is used to determine maximum and minimum preference value and item- and user-ids. Regarding the users I'm planning to have only anonymous "profiles" anyways - so would it then be ok to pass along fake data?

How's that supports to work - the Mahout examples (1) and the MiA book don't give any answers on that but both state that pre-computation is the way to go :(

---

(1) I'm running on Mahout 0.7 but also looked into trunk already.

(2) I had to transfer the generated similarity matrix into a textual format myself of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the same `DataModel` that was fed to the similarity computation. The recommender's output is certainly a function of the similarities, but, also the original data of course! That's why it's an input.

You could in theory build similarities off a different `DataModel` than the data you are actually making recommendations from. It's possible and might make sense in some cases but is not normal.

Comment: So precomputing the similarities then "only" reduces the ramp-up time of my recommender, but won't help me to get recommendations going for larger amounts of data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you are using a similarity-based recommender, you compute similarities as part of making any recommendation. Whether you pre-compute or something is an orthogonal question.

Comment: As I wrote ... I did use the ItemSimilarityJob to "prepare" the similarities and I'd love to use the recommender mainly to make recommendations for  anonymous users (which then should run for live requests and not as preprocessing step) - therefore I wanted to avoid that all data has to be loaded into the DataModel once again ...

Comment: Generally the user has to be in the `DataModel` given to the `Recommender` in order to make recommendations for the user. What you give to `ItemSimilarity` is actually separate, though usually still the same data. If you want to make really anonymous recs, you may actually want a most-similar-items method actually, or, look at the `PlusAnonymousUser*` classes / hacks. But again, you feed your main data to the `Recommender`, and, to similarity metrics.